# How to upload a website for a particular region/area ?

Tags: web, web-testing

I have developed a website. Now I want to launch the Beta version of my website for testing purpose. So i want it to be launched in a particular region/area (in my city only). I have my own server but i have no idea how to launch my website in defined area.

do you have any suggestions of how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to explicitly block visitors who attempt to access your site from outside your "defined area"?

Comment: Yes sir exactly... is their any way to do so

Answer (score 0):

uhm, you don't and you can't - at least not reliably.

Sites that do offer a region-specific version, like Craigslist (which has a site for each city, e.g. seattle.craigslist.org, london.craigslist.org) do not deny access to visitors from outside these areas, the geographic designations are just for the user's convenience, because a user in London has no interest in a Yard sale in Seattle.

Some sites do block regions, often for rights reasons, such as SouthPark.com blocking UK visitors and the BBC's iPlayer blocking non-UK visitors, this is because they don't have the necessary copyright licenses to broadcast or distributed content outside their local area (the USA and UK respectively).

Blocking users is accomplished by subscribing to, or maintaining an IP block database which associates IP address ranges with geographic areas - this information is freely available from a variety of online sources (google for "ip geolocation database"). However the information is granular only to the country-level, though in some places (like the US) you'll be able to get it down to the nearest state and possibly city - the information is often gleaned from the registered office address of the ISP that is assigned a particular IP address range - so an ISP in Seattle might also serve customers in Everett (a nearby city), but the IP address database would only say they're in Seattle, not Everett. This inherent inaccuracy is why those scammy "Single mom from %yourTown% discovers weird trick to reverse aging!" ads often get your town completely wrong.

However remember that blocking users because of their geographical location is always a bad idea: it will only breed resentment amongst your visitors - though it can be the lesser of two evils, such as in the case of broadcasters (where they'd be denied from streaming anything at all), but for regular websites that are not bound by geographical exclusivity contracts it's just evil.